# Checking IP and Port before sending data using if

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an application to control a raspberry pi and I really need help because I never used android to communicate with external devices.
For testing, I want to send data to my log and my ip. But before the transferring, the user has to type in the ip and the port. For this, the activity has 2 TextViews. When I delate my query it works.
So I think, my if condition is wrong.
This is my code for sending data with button click:

```
    button_connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Check IP and Port
            if (editText_ip.equals(server_ip) && editText_port.equals(server_port)) {
                //Connect client to car
                ArrayMap<String, Object> putParams = new ArrayMap<>();
                putParams.put("signal1", 65);
                Log.d(Test, "index=" + Test);
                RestClientHelper.getInstance().put(base_url, putParams, new RestClientHelper.RestClientListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    }
                    //Connecting successful
                    @Override
                    public void onError(String error) {
                    // Connecting failed
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
```

The problem is, the checking isn't working.

Comment: `if` is not a loop

Comment: And Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: i know but i hoped the guys could help me... and sorry for bad english, i didn't mean a loop, but query

Comment: I hope my question is better now

Comment: What is the type of `editText_ip`? If it's indeed `EditText` as the name suggests you would need something along the lines of `editText_ip.getText().equals(server_ip)`.

Comment: Ok thank you i forgot that, you're right.

Comment: And at which point of the listener I do the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a solution. In the end it was very simple.

I wasn't using the correct way to get the String out of the Edit Text field.

```
    button_connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Connect client to car
                String ip = editText_ip.getText().toString();
                String port = editText_port.getText().toString();
                if (ip.equals(server_ip) && port.equals(server_port)) {
                    ArrayMap<String, Object> putParams = new ArrayMap<>();
                    putParams.put("direction", 24); //Test server
                    Log.d(Test, "Test=" + Test);    //Test Log
                    RestClientHelper.getInstance().put(base_url, putParams, new RestClientHelper.RestClientListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String response) {
                            //Connecting successful
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String error) {
                            // Connecting failed
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```